# jquery minicolors - show or not color-picker

Tags: jquery, show, color-picker

I have many inputs. Every of them have the 'data-allowed' attribute set as hidden true or false. These attributes are dynamicaly and asynchronously changing.

I need to make 'onclick' function. If 'data-allowed' is set to "TRUE" show minicolors color-picker - but when is set to "FALSE" do not shot color-picker, just make alert('Color is not allowed in this minute.')

HTML

```
<input data-allowed='true' class='minicolors' />
<input data-allowed='false' class='minicolors' />
<input data-allowed='true' class='minicolors' />
<input data-allowed='false' class='minicolors' />
```

jQuery

```
$(".minicolors").minicolors({
      textfield: false,
      opacity: true,
      change: function (hex, opacity) {
               // change color
      }
});
```

Comment: `class='.minicolors'` makes no sense. `class='minicolors'` should be used instead.